# Android logs, What means verbosity?

Tags: android, logging, verbosity

According Android documentation about Log.e, Log.v,...: "The order in terms of verbosity, from least to most is ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, VERBOSE. Verbose should never be compiled into an application except during development"

My questions is, What means verbosity? Because If i use Log.v("TAG","STRING"); or Log.e("TAG","STRING"); i see the same info.

Comment: verbose means list every thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Verbosity here, simply put, means the level of "casualness" of that message. Error is obviously the most important, and hence least casual, while verbose is the other way around.

You will see the same content when using any of them, but when using logcat filters you can filter only errors or any other level, in which case it'll only show messages of that level.

As per Docs

> The order in terms of verbosity, from least to most is ERROR, WARN,
>   INFO, DEBUG, VERBOSE.

Comment: ... messages of that level or higher. For example, filtering on warnings shows also errors.

Comment: Thanks but then, Why Android recomends don't use v in final programas if there is not differences?

Comment: @juan There is a difference. You're supposed to use v for printing out random information you would only need for debugging, and not in a production app. In a production app, you should at best only print out errors and warnings, and in some cases debug logs.

Comment: Thenthe difference is only about conventions and when use one or another, not about more or less info, more or less performance,...   Thanks

Comment: The difference is that they help you tell apart different kinds of information, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Verbose means that it is the least important Log in the logging Tier.

from the docs https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

listed in order from the highest to lowest priority

```
Log.e(String, String) (error)
Log.w(String, String) (warning)
Log.i(String, String) (information)
Log.d(String, String) (debug)
Log.v(String, String) (verbose)
```

Answer (score 0):

check this similar [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7959379/931982)

**Log.v:** Use this when you want to go absolutely nuts with your logging. If for some reason you've decided to log every little thing in a particular part of your app, use the Log.v tag.