# Logcat: Difference between Log levels?

Tags: android, logcat

I am developing an Android Application in Android Studio. I would like to know the difference between the different Log levels in Logcat?

```
Verbose

Debug

Info

Warn

Error

Assert
```

Comment: They are, well ..., different log levels.

Comment: search before ask please http://stackoverflow.com/a/7959379/4116091

Answer (score 8):

***Verbose:*** Show all log messages (the default).

***Debug:*** Show debug log messages that are useful during development only, as well as the message levels lower in this list.

***Info:*** Show expected log messages for regular usage, as well as the message levels lower in this list.

***Warn:*** Show possible issues that are not yet errors, as well as the message levels lower in this list.

***Error:*** Show issues that have caused errors, as well as the message level lower in this list.

***Assert:*** Show issues that the developer expects should never happen.

Answer (score 5):

There are technically no negative consequences for using log levels incorrectly; the different levels are merely a way to categorize your log output. For errors, use Error. For general information, use Info. If you're printing out absolutely everything, use Verbose (etc.)

By using appropriate log levels, you will benefit from color-coding in Logcat and the ability to filter out the levels you aren't interested in during debugging.