# A table that contains View objects tags

Tags: java, android, logging

First of all I must say I'm new to both Android dev and Java.
I'm trying to find a list of the tags that are used for logging in Android studio.
The examples I've been researching include using:

```
Log.i(tag:"Info","message");
Log.i(tag:"Values","another message");
Log.i(tag:"Seekbar changed", "and another message");
```

I tried for the past couple of hours to find a document online, that has a table to describe the reserved tags for View objects, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no fixed list of "reserved tags" one can use for logging in Android. You decide for yourself which tags you want to use and what additional information about the state of your objects or primitive types you want to display.

The `Log` class has six different log levels (debug, error, info, verbose, warn and wtf [What a Terrible Failure]) and corresponding (static) methods (`Log.d`, `Log.e`, `Log.i`, `Log.v`, `Log.w` and `Log.wtf`) each of which you call with two string parameters, one string parameter and one `Throwable` or two string parameters and one `Throwable`.

The most commonly used is probably the variant with two string parameters, one parameter for a tag (chosen by you) and one parameter for a message (also chosen by you). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7959379/3356270) for information about which level to choose.

During debugging I often use commands like this one:

```
Log.e(String.valueOf(myIntVariable), String.valueOf(myOtherVariable));
```

Let me explain the reason for using the `Log` class like this. I use the `e`rror level because it will give you *red* entries in the LogCat output (inside an IDE, e.g. Android Studio), and the same IDE will also let you filter out all logs below the error level. However, this is for debugging only; make sure to get rid of those log commands before your app enters production.

Instead of using logs in the way I do, you can also use breakpoints in the debug mode. I guess it is mainly a question of taste if you prefer one or the other. `Toast`s would be third option (with more boilerplate though).

If you use logs a lot in your code, it makes sense to use real tags. Either you define a string called TAG (or something else) in your class, or you put the name of the containing method as the first parameter. This will give you a sense of the order by which your methods are being called. You can also use other tags as well, and it doesn't have to follow a specific convention either (though you should have a system for it to make sense of it).