# What is the meaning of alphabets in android studio logcat?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

While running the application in android studio logcat is generated and there are alphabets at the beginning of every line. what is the meaning of those alphabets?

[image: LogCat]?

[image: d]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Log.v(), Log.d(), Log.i(), Log.w(), Log.e() - When to use each one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959263/android-log-v-log-d-log-i-log-w-log-e-when-to-use-each-one)

Comment: Yes @Umair, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin, Milan Tejani I appreciate efforts of both of you but let's not play this upvote game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these alphabet is for various log options:

see this link : [Log option](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log#summary)

`A` is for `ASSERT`

`D` is for `DEBUG`

`E` is for `ERROR`

`I` is for `INFO`

`V` is for `VERBOSE`

`W` is for `WARN`

you can filter log message by above option by clicking here so you can see that particular log only:

[image: Select log option]

Answer (score 2):

You have choosen verbose logcat. In logcat some logs are info (I), some are errors (E) , some are warnings (W) and some other logs.

See here:

[image]

Comment: i already upvoted your ans yesterday. yous ans has one vote which is given by me