# Logs in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie of Android Studio.
I have a problem with display the logs in my app.
For example:

```
String timeStamp = new 
SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cycle);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cykleoncreate);
    Log.d("[ " + timeStamp + "]", "[onCreate]");
```

I only want to display this log in my app. How can I do it?

Comment: You have coded it right, you just have to select "Logcat" from the bottom nav menu inside android studio, and select debug in the third drop-down menu from left in the pop up window. After running the app you will be able to see your log. If not, type "onCreate" in the search bar.

Answer (score 1):

you can display the logs by Toast or set in textView

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),timeStamp,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

or

```
textView.setText(timeStamp);
```

Comment: `timeStamp` is already a string, according to OP's code, so adding `""+timeStamp` is just messy and doesn't do anything

Comment: textView.setText(timeStamp) it works well, thank you. But if I wanted add a string to my timeStamp? 
textView.setText(timeStamp + "myString")? It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is write but you can get confused as in where's the log, Log has `tag` and `message`, Tags are usually Activity or fragment name so that its easier for one to locate from where did a particular `error` or `message` came from, and you can include anything in the message part of it.

we have different types of `logs` this can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959263/android-log-v-log-d-log-i-log-w-log-e-when-to-use-each-one)

You will find a `logcat` button on bottom side left side of android studio from there you can select depending on which type you want to see? in your case it's `debug`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it works well

```
textView.setText(timeStamp)
```

But I don't know why it doesn't work, when I want to build my string:

```
textView.setText(timeStamp + "my string")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Actually [Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log) is not displaying in app , it will display in android studio . For displaying in app , we need to use [Toast](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts) . your code is working fine you can check it in your android studio , as its shown in image [image: Log in Android Studio] We can display like this `Log.d("onCreate", timeStamp);` and search using TAG as onCreate.